# Is there a way to pretend that a handleCheck from a togglebutton never happend?

Tags: c#, wpf

I am working on a program, that connects my client to a server via `SSH`. I am using a toggle button for the connect/disconnect function in `wpf`. I want to implement such that, when I press the toggle button and it fails to connect, the button should return to its original state, "**unchecked**".

I tried it with `toggle_btn.IsChecked = false;` This sets the button in a state of not being pressed. However it still runs the code as if I unchecked it, which I do not want. I just want the button to pretend nothing ever happened, so the user can verify his password and try again.

```
 private void HandleCheck(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
          //connection to the ssh client
                    if (capt.Connect(str.Split(';')[0], 22, str.Split(';')[1], 
                    str.Split(';')[2]) == false)
            {                 
                    btn_con.IsChecked = false;
              }

        }
```

If I use the `.IsChecked`, it runs the code contained in the `HandleUnchecked` function. However you can't disconnect something that has never been connected which is why it throws an exception. I could catch this exception, however I want to know if there is a better way to prevent the code from executing.

```
        private void HandleUnchecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            capt.DisconnectSSH();
        }
```

Comment: After you have set IsChecked = false; do a e.Handled = true; and it should work

Comment: you should have a Property in your class that knows if you are connected or not. something like `if(capt.IsConnected)            capt.DisconnectSSH();`

Comment: @NawedNabiZada that will not work as it will handle the wrong event not the newly created event that was caused by the changing of the IsChecked Property

Comment: Ok. perhaps I do not understand the question. And I just realized that there is a Handled and UnHandled event. Perhaps doing this whole thing in a IF/ELSE statement will give you the desired behavior. If you don't handle the UnChecked event both events will be routed to the Checked event.

Comment: @DenisSchaf hey thanks, I already use that property to verify whether a connection is even existing. However, I always receive a NullReferenceException for the SFTP client. This is why I try to reserve that the event ever happend.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can remove and add the Uncheck event. And also make a delay to reverse the event in the GUI.

```
private void ToggleButton_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            // IF condition
            {
                Task.Run(() =>
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(500);
                    Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
                    {
                        tgButton.Unchecked -= tgButton_Unchecked;
                        tgButton.IsChecked = false;
                    });                 
                }).
                ContinueWith((tsk) =>
                {
                    tgButton.Unchecked += tgButton_Unchecked;
                });
            }
        }
```

Comment: I think this could be simplified significantly with `async` / `await`.  You wouldn't have to worry about manually spinning up a task, or marshalling the UI calls.

Comment: @BradleyUffner : I tried aync and await and removed Thread.Sleep(500);  but toggle button behaved like not pressed.  To get the pressed and reverse effect I added Thread.Sleep(500);.

Comment: For `async` / `await` to work, you would want to convert the `Thread.Sleep` to `Task.Wait`.